# Using Ansible, how can I start a GCP VM instance which is currently stopped?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

I have a GCP Compute Engine VM instance that is in a stopped state. How can I start it up, specifically using Ansible?

Please note that this must be in its own Ansible playbook, as opposed to the playbook that created the VM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible cannot connect to your device (or machine) if your SSHD process is off.

so How can Ansible connect to your device (or machine) if not only SSHD process is off, but also the whole machine is off ?

Ansible connects on yourbehalf to your machine and makes sure that your desired state meets the actual state.

However, you have solution as your are dealing with IaaS.

In this case, you need to target your **localhost** and call [the module `gcp_compute_instance`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/gcp_compute_instance_module.html#parameter-status) with `status: RUNNING`

```
- name: create a instance
  gcp_compute_instance:
    name: test_object
    machine_type: n1-standard-1
    #. ...
    status: RUNNING # <-- this is what u need
```

Please make sure you have **ansible 2.8 or above** otherwise there is no param called status in the previous versions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @abdennour-toumi.

Correct, status: RUNNING works well.

Be sure to set the deletion_protection parameter, else the playbook fails.

```
---
- name: Start a GCP instance which is currently stopped
  hosts: to_start_up
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Start a GCP VM instance which is currently stopped
      gcp_compute_instance:
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname_short }}"
        deletion_protection: no
        machine_type: "{{ gcp_ce_machine_type }}"
        zone: "{{ gcp_ce_zone }}"
        project: "{{ gcp_ce_project_name }}"
        auth_kind: serviceaccount
        service_account_file: "{{ gcp_ce_service_account_keyfile }}"
        status: RUNNING
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Comment: Welcome @DGB and thank you for the followup. Congratulations also for understanding "target your localhost" as  i see you used "delegate_to: localhost"